# vBulletin 3.8: How to display array values in templates

Tags: vbulletin

My problem in here (**probably**) is that $db->fetch_array won't show all the results from the db. I don't know what happens but I just get 1 of the 3 results, I tried many things even I changed the query a bit. Do you have any ideas why I can't get all the results in here?

It's for vBulletin 3.8 btw.

Thanks people.

```
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'showthis') {


    $rel = $db->query_first("
        SELECT *
        FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "anexampletable
        WHERE fromuserid OR touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . "
        AND confirmstatus =1
    ");


if ($rel)  {

$queryrel = $db->query_read("
                SELECT *
        FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "anexampletable
        WHERE fromuserid OR touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . "
        AND confirmstatus =1
        ");            

while ($queryre = $db->fetch_array($queryrel)) { 

if ($queryre['reltype'] == '1') {

               $ty = " is something else ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '2') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '3') {

               $ty = " is something else ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '4') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '5') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '6') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '7') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '8') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '9') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '10') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '11') {

               $ty = " is something else ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '12') {

               $ty = " is something else ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '13') {

               $ty = " is something ";

} else if ($queryre['reltype'] == '14') {

               $ty = " is something ";
} else {

$ty = " is default ";

}

$sender = $queryre['fromusername'];
$receiver = $queryre['tousername'];
$showit = $sender . $ty . $receiver;

}

eval('print_output("' . fetch_template('relationships') . '");');

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is saying:

```
WHERE `fromuserid` has any value 

OR (touserid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']).
```

If you want the rows where either `fromuserid` matches the userid or `touserid` matches the userid, try this:

```
$queryrel = $db->query_read("
        SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "anexampletable

        WHERE (fromuserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ") 
        OR (touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ")

        AND confirmstatus =1
        ");
```

**Update:**
It's hard to determine the problem without knowing the data you're working with. I've created a test that outputs the data your code is working with, you'll be able to see what the individual parts of your query are returning and then can determine where the problem lies.

Modify your file temporarily by placing this code just before the code in your example (you'll need to use the correct table name). Then edit your question and paste the output at the bottom.

```
echo "vBulletin User ID = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'];

$test_query1 = $db->query_read("
  SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "anexampletable
  WHERE (fromuserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ")
");  

$t1_count = 0;
echo "Test From User ID Results<br />";
while ($test1_output = $db->fetch_array($test_query1)) {
  $t1_count++;
  echo "Test From User Result " . $t1_count . "<br />";
  echo "From User ID = " . $test1_output['fromuserid'] . "<br />";
  echo "To User ID = " . $test1_output['touserid'] . "<br />";
  echo "Confirm Status = " . $test1_output['confirmstatus'] . "<br />";
  echo "Relationship Status = " . $test1_output['reltype'] . "<br />";
}


$test_query2 = $db->query_read("
  SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "anexampletable
  WHERE (touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ")
");  

$t2_count = 0;
echo "<br /><br />Test To User ID Results<br />";
while ($test2_output = $db->fetch_array($test_query2)) {
  $t2_count++;
  echo "Test To User Result " . $t2_count . "<br />";
  echo "From User ID = " . $test2_output['fromuserid'] . "<br />";
  echo "To User ID = " . $test2_output['touserid'] . "<br />";
  echo "Confirm Status = " . $test2_output['confirmstatus'] . "<br />";
  echo "Relationship Status = " . $test2_output['reltype'] . "<br />";
}

exit();
```

**Final Code?**
It appears that there were two problems:
**1)** The query needed to be modified:
Original:

```
fromuserid OR touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . "
```

Updated:

```
(fromuserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . " 
OR 
touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ")
```

**Updated 07/05/2012**
**2)** You can't loop through arrays in vb3 templates, so we'll concatenate strings.
The $showit variable being output for use in the template is a string. It's being overwritten by each successive pass through the while loop so that only the last result is sent to the template. Instead of using `$showit = xxx;`, use `$showit .= xxx;` with `.=`.

I've updated the last 15 lines or so of the code below.

---

**You can look at how the forum page is generated to learn more.**
Open the upload\forumdisplay.php file. The `while` loop that creates the list of threads starts here:
upload\forumdisplay.php(962)
`while ($thread = $db->fetch_array($threads))`

The output for each thread is generated using the "threadbit" template and added to the `$threadbit` string here:
upload\forumdisplay.php(1000)
`eval('$threadbit .= "' . fetch_template('threadbit') . '";');`

The "FORUMDISPLAY" template is output at the end:
upload\forumdisplay.php(1056)
`eval('print_output("' . fetch_template('FORUMDISPLAY') . '");');`

If you look at the FORUMDISPLAY template, you'll find that the `$threadbit` string is used about 1/5 from the beginning.

---

Try the code below and see how it works, I replaced the series of `else if` statements with a `switch()` statement. It's more efficient.

```
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'showthis') {

  // Make standalone query, easy to output query string and run it directly for testing
  $rel_sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "anexampletable
    WHERE (fromuserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . "
    OR touserid = " . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . ")
    AND confirmstatus =1";

  $queryrel = $db->query_read($rel_sql);

  if ($db->num_rows($queryrel))
  {
    while ($queryre = $db->fetch_array($queryrel))
    {
      switch ($queryre['reltype'])
      {
        case 1:
          $ty = " do something 1 ";
          break;
        case 2:
          $ty = " do something 2 ";
          break;
        case 3:
          $ty = " do something 3 ";
          break;

        // Add as many cases as needed
        .......
        case xxx:
          $ty = " do something xxx ";
          break;
        .......

        default:
          $ty = " is default ";
      }

      $sender = $queryre['fromusername'];
      $receiver = $queryre['tousername'];

      // UPDATED FROM HERE DOWN on 07/05/2012
      // Add to $showit with ".=" rather than overwriting it with "=".

      // Method One
      // If the output is simple, try this.
      // I added a line break after each entry.
      $showit .= $sender . $ty . $receiver . "<br />";

      OR

      // Method Two
      // If the output is complex.
      // Create a separate template and store the output in $showit
      // Remember to add the new template to the $actiontemplates array.
      eval('$showit .= "' . fetch_template('showit') . '";');
    }

    eval('print_output("' . fetch_template('relationships') . '");');
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't show all the results, again. It shows only 1 and I am trying to find out why, I can say that I am playing with this code for over 20 days daily but nothing seems to work. From what you can see guys it is a simple user-relationship script that it will pull the data from the database. Any other ideas from gurus? I am a newbie and trying to learn from my mistakes. $ty = the number of the type of the relationship, I mean I had no simpler idea on how to pull it, but again, it won't show all the results, I have no idea. Any help? Thank you very very much codewaggle btw for your help!!!!

Comment: Please run the test I've added to my answer and put the results in your question.

Comment: vBulletin User ID = 1Test From User ID Results
Test From User Result 1
From User ID = 1
To User ID = 2
Confirm Status = 1
Relationship Status = 4
Test From User Result 2
From User ID = 1
To User ID = 2
Confirm Status = 1
Relationship Status = 6
Test From User Result 3
From User ID = 1
To User ID = 2
Confirm Status = 1
Relationship Status = 3


Test To User ID Results

Comment: Actually, it worked the way you did it right now, but I can't get why it's not working with my code before. There are only 3 records and now it shows all, correctly. But if I will add the code at the first post, it will show only 1. Maybe the problem lies that my code has been added in the profile.php (core file)? I didn't added a plugin, I just wrote a new " if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'showthis') ".

Comment: Can I know how I will display it after evaluating the template, etc? It still won't show the results with my code.

Comment: Your relationships are:
Array ----- This was the result now. Any ideas? The code looks perfect, but why it is not working again? Haha, it will drive me crazy -----

Comment: The `$showit` variable is an array, you need to loop through the array in your template, if you just output `$showit`, it will output "array". Please add the code from your template to the end of your question.

Comment: $stylevar[htmldoctype]
<html dir="$stylevar[textdirection]" lang="$stylevar[languagecode]">
<head>
<title>$vboptions[bbtitle]</title>
$headinclude
</head>
<body>
$header

$navbar
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="$stylevar[cellpadding]" cellspacing="$stylevar[cellspacing]" border="0" width="100%" align="center">

<tr class="tcat">
  <td>Relationships:</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="alt1">

$showit

</tr>
</table>

$footer
</body>
</html>


    </td>
</tr>Sorry,Can you guide me on what how to make it or to replace my template so I can see the difference and learn? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to display multiple rows in vb3. You can't loop through arrays within templates, so you need to add each row to the same string. Use HTML tags to show rows on separate lines. I included info about where you can look at the vb code to see how they do it.

Comment: Ok, this was the solution, thank you very very very very much. You rock! I am reading also what you said and I understood the process, thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome, if this answered the question, you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: It occurred to me that you might not know about voting. If you see a good (or bad) question or answer, you can click the up or down arrow next to it and the number between the arrows will increase or decrease. Take a look at this entry from the FAQ: [What is reputation?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). You can also read the whole FAQ by clicking the link at the top of each page, there's lots of good info. I'm not mentioning this so that you'll up vote my answer, there's no need, you already indicated that you think it's a good answer by clicking the check mark.